# Crear un tabla historial con trigger o html , mysql php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una tabla de personas y quiero que hacer un historial de cambios en una tabla solo si cambio de nivel o año que se inserte a una tabla llamada historia,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
no quiero que se inserte si actualizo su dirección.
SOLO si actualizo su nivel Y año,
NO tengo idea de como CREAR EL HISTORIAL y el trigger correctamente.

```
CREATE TRIGGER  actualize_historial AFTER  UPDATE ON personal
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO historial  id_cliente=id , nivel=NEW.nivel, anio=NEW.anio ;
```

Esto es lo que se me ocurre,  con trigger

por otro lado me gustaria hacerlo manual pasarlos hacer una lista y pasarlos seleccionando un check de los datos que quiero crear el historial dar clic a un boton  y pasar muchos datos.
Pero esto no se como programarlo (check y boton) para pasarlos por grupo.

```
<?php
    require('conexion.php');

    $query="SELECT *  FROM personal";

    $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

?>




<table>
            <thead>
                <tr class="centro">
                    <td>id_cliente</td>
                    <td>Nombre</td>
                    <td>Género</td>
                    <td>dirección</td>
                    <td>nivel</td>
                    <td>año</td>
                    <td>accion</td>
                </tr>
                <form>
                <tbody>


                    <?php while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc()){ 
                            echo ' 

                        <tr>
                        <td hidden><input name="idEnumera[]" value="'.$row['id_cliente'].'" /></td>

                            <td><input type="number" name="idEmpl['.$row['id_cliente'].']" value="'.  $row['id_cliente'] .'"  /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="ciudad['.$row['id_cliente'].']" value="'.  $row['nombre'] .'"  /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="ciudad['.$row['id_cliente'].']" value="'.  $row['genero'] .'"  /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="cargo['.$row['id_cliente'].']" value="'.  $row['direccion'] .'"  /></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="mail['.$row['id_cliente'].']" value="'.  $row['nivel'] .'"  /></td>
                            <td><input type="text"  value="'.  $row['id_cliente'] .'" value="'.  $row['anio'] .'"  /></td>

                            <td><input type="checkbox"  value="'.  $row['id_cliente'] .'" value=""  /></td>



                        </tr>


                        '; 

                     } ?>



                </tbody>
                    <input type="submit" name="Crear historial" value="pasarlos al historial" class="btn btn-info col-md-offset-9">
                    </form>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta pregunta ya tiene respuesta aquí, espero le sirva de ayuda: [Actualizar solo si cambia un campo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296313/mysql-trigger-after-update-only-if-row-has-changed)

Lo que tendría es que evaluar si el campo nuevo es diferente a el campo antiguo:

```
IF NEW.campo <> OLD.campo or NEW.b THEN  
  INSERT INTO historial  id_cliente=id , nivel=NEW.nivel, anio=NEW.anio ;
END IF
```

Comment: Si la pregunta ya tiene una respuesta, no se debe contestar, se debe reportar como duplicada y cerrarla. Ahora, si la pregunta no es de este sitio, estaria bueno hacer una respuesta de nivel para que nos quede como referencia...

Comment: pero tendria que crear un begin  dentro del trigger como debería ser completo dentro del trigger?